# How do I have this line of code print out the greeting, excluding some characters

Tags: python

```
#This is my string known as "greeting".

greeting = "hello how are you, what?" 

#This prints the greeting the normal way.

print(greeting.title())

#This prints the greeting backwards and excluding the chosen letter "h" on the outside.  

print (greeting.title()[:greeting.find("h"):-1] + greeting[greeting.rfind("h")-1:5])
```

How do I make this print out the greeting, excluding the outside letter "h", but leaving the inside letter "h" where it is.

I need the output to be:

```
"Hello How Are You, What?"

"W ,uoY erA woH olle"
```

With my current code output is:

```
"Hello How Are You, What?"

"?tahW ,uoY erA woH olle"
```

I just need the '?tah" to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
greeting = "hello how are you, what?"
title = greeting.title()
print(title)
print(title[greeting.rfind('h') - 1:greeting.find('h'):-1])
```

This outputs:

```
Hello How Are You, What?
W ,uoY erA woH olle
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/UnknownMustyFlatassembler

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would be *another* way to achieve this.

```
>>> import re
>>> greeting = "hello how are you, what?"
>>> re.sub(r'^[hH](.*)[hH].*?$', r'\1', greeting.title())[::-1]
'W ,uoY erA woH olle'
```

We're going to match everything between either `h` or `H` and the *last* `h` or `H` in the string and replace the whole string with just that, then reverse it with `[::-1]`.